# Fuerte, Ubuntu 12.04, ARM = error

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just following instructions on
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

```
robot@robot:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
robot@robot:~$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
--2012-06-24 00:34:40--  http://packages.ros.org/ros.key
Resolving packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)... 157.22.19.137
Connecting to packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)|157.22.19.137|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1162 (1.1K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

100%[=============================================================================================>] 1,162       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2012-06-24 00:34:41 (18.2 MB/s) - written to stdout [1162/1162]

OK
robot@robot:~$ 
robot@robot:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise InRelease
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release.gpg     
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com precise InRelease       
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg 
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/restricted armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
robot@robot:~$
```

I actually see http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-armel/ exists and difference is "armhf" and "arm". Maybe this looks like ubuntu basic problem but I think at moment ROS documentation just missing this little hint how to overcome this "hf" problem. Yes I searched in Google and ROS answers and haven't got good idea yet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37129/fuerte,-ubuntu-12.04,-arm-=-error/) by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2012-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

And as usually happens, after asking I seem to found solution myself. Two things to be done:

1. Make new file /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch containing one line only:

   foreign-architecture armel
2. Add [arch=armel] into /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list like this:

   deb [arch=armel] http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main

Now "apt-get update" was able to fetch all he needs.

---

Originally posted by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) with karma: 161 on 2012-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on 2012-06-23**:
And stuck again. There is no ROS packages to install with apt-get install :(. Nothing shown in install instructions works for ARM.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-06-23**:
Willow Garage is not currently building any binary packages for ARM, so you shouldn't expect to find any with apt-get. You could try installing from source, but many things will likely be broken on ARM. Was there someplace on the wiki that led you to believe ARM packages should be available?

**Comment by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on 2012-06-24**:
Wiki says ubuntu is OK and I do have ubuntu. Also as indicated I found some armel directory and assumed I just do something wrong.